Overwrite a column of an array in AppScript
Say I have a 2D array with n rows, e.g.
table = [["Team 1", 3, 3, 0, 0, 9, 1],
         ["Team 2", 3, 0, 1, 2, 1, 3],
         ["Team 3", 3, 2, 0, 1, 6, 2],
         ["Team 4", 3, 0, 1, 2, 1, 3]]

Then say I have a 1D array of length n, e.g.
newRank = [1, 4, 2, 3]

How would I overwrite column i of table with newRank? E.g. column 6
Is there such thing as column slicing as in Python's Numpy?

@zer00ne   You seemed to have closed this question as a duplicate of a php question, while this is tagged as JavaScript. Was that intentional?

@TheMaster I'm getting new glasses this week. I voted to reopen. It needs a [mcve].

There is no such thing as column slicing in  JavaScript. You have to loop through. To do it in place,


/*<ignore>*/console.config({maximize:true,timeStamps:false,autoScroll:false});/*</ignore>*/
table = [["Team 1", 3, 3, 0, 0, 9, 1],
     ["Team 2", 3, 0, 1, 2, 1, 3],
     ["Team 3", 3, 2, 0, 1, 6, 2],
     ["Team 4", 3, 0, 1, 2, 1, 3]];    
newRank = [1, 4, 2, 3];   
col = 6; 
newRank.forEach((v,r) => table[r][col]=v);
console.table(table)
<!-- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375985/ -->    <script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>




The other way is to transpose the array, replace one row, and re-transpose.

@doubleunary It makes sense as a formula in sheets, but in JavaScript, transpose, replace, re-transpose is overly complicated in terms of number of ops done/efficiency ... just one transpose requires moving (almost)all the elements in the array.

Yes, but pure JavaScript performance is very seldom an issue in Apps Script. The two approaches will give different results when newRank.length doesn't match table.length. It's unclear which one the OP is after.

@doubleunary Thanks for the transpose suggestion. You can assume newRank.length always equals table.length, which is why I have defined them both as n in the question. Since column slicing doesn't exist, I think I'd rather iterate down the column than transpose the array twice.

One way to do that is to transpose the array, replace one row, and re-transpose, like this:
function test() {
  const table = [
    ["Team 1", 3, 3, 0, 0, 9, 1],
    ["Team 2", 3, 0, 1, 2, 1, 3],
    ["Team 3", 3, 2, 0, 1, 6, 2],
    ["Team 4", 3, 0, 1, 2, 1, 3]
  ];
  const newRank = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
  console.log(replaceColumn_(table, 6, newRank));
}

function replaceColumn_(array, rowIndex, values) {
  const _transpose = a => Object.keys(a[0]).map(c => a.map(r => r[c]));
  const newArray = _transpose(array);
  newArray[rowIndex] = values;
  return _transpose(newArray);
}

See Object.keys().
